# Using union to convert array of four uint8_t to uint32_t in ANSI C

Tags: c, arrays, union, c99

I'm working on some code in XC8 (C compiler for Microchip 8 bit microcontrollers, probably based on gcc).

I'm using many byte array -> whatever and whatever -> byte array conversions similar to this:

```
inline int32_t GetInt32(uint8_t b3, uint8_t b2, uint8_t b1, uint8_t b0)
{
    int32_t b_31_24 = (((int32_t)b3) << 24);
    int32_t b_23_16 = (((int32_t)b2) << 16);
    int32_t b_15_08 = (((int32_t)b1) << 8);
    int32_t b_07_00 = b0;

    return b_31_24 + b_23_16 + b_15_08 + b_07_00;        
}
```

**Can I just use union like this?**

```
typedef union {
    int32_t int32value;
    uint32_t uint32value;
    int16_t[2] int16words;
    uint16_t[2] uint16words;
    int8_t[4] int8bytes;
    uint8_t[4] uint8bytes;
} union32_t;
```

**I want to reduce CPU and/or memory usage.**

**Lets assume:**

- this code will be used with same compiler
- I know what endiannes is and it won't change without my knowledge :)
- I know that diffrent compilers may have diffrent behavior regarding alignment (I have tested Microchip XC8, XC32, some STM compiler).

**Why I'm asking about this?**

I want to make sure, if there are no issues with arrays like "undefined behavior" when casting `byte array` to `int` etc.

Comment: All you are doing is inviting the compiler to burn down your house.   Modern C is not appropriate for low level programming like that.

Comment: @mevets who told you that?  do not trust this person anymore....

Comment: @P__J__: The type of "Modern C" favored by the clang and gcc optimizers is only appropriate for applications which will be run exclusively in contexts where they will never ever maliciously-constructed data, or where nothing they could possibly do, even maliciously, would have any unacceptable consequences.  But who says anyone should use "modern C"?

Comment: Should be fine as long as you don't break any other rules in the process.  It would help to see an example of how you want to use the union, though, to be sure.

Comment: actually gcc developers prefer union punning. there was a long discussion about it.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons What do you mean by "any other rules in the process"?

Comment: Strict aliasing.  If you already have a `uint8_t[4] x;` and alias it to your union with `union32_t *y = x;`, you'll have issues.  Just wanted to be clear on that since there wasn't an example of exactly how you intended to use it in the question.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: Is there anything in the Standard or the documentation for clang or gcc that would imply that `someUnion.arr[i]` would not be equivalent to `*((someUnion.arr)+(i))`?  Neither gcc nor clang processes the latter form correctly, and unless there is a documented reason for the distinction I would regard any apprent meaningful treatment of the former with suspicion.

Comment: @supercat That might be worthy of its own question.  I'll try to take a look at the documentation when I get a chance.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: From my reading of the Standard, `someUnion.arr[i]` decomposes `someUnion.arr` into a pointer, indexes it, and uses accesses the storage using the pointer, which would of course be an lvalue of the element type, which would only be defined behavior for a character-type array unless an access via pointer which a compiler should be able to recognize as being formed from the union would be considered an access to the union.  IMHO, the authors of the Standard intended the latter, but neither clang nor gcc upholds that philosophy.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: Probably the biggest source of confusion is that the authors of the Standard have for 30+ years failed to reach any kind of consensus as to the extent of its jurisdiction over programs that aren't *strictly* conforming, so it's unclear whether their failure to allow a non-portable behavior means they intended to forbid it, or merely considered to be outside the Standard's jurisdiction to allow or forbid and thus refrained from passing any judgment whatsoever.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html

Comment: @supercat gcc is OK with union punning.

Comment: @P__J__: They're okay with *direct* member-access lvalues, but `someUnion.array[i]` isn't defined by the Standard as "access element `i` of `someUnion.array`, but is instead *defined* as "take the address of the first element of `someUnion.array`, add `i`, and then dereference the resulting pointer".  I think gcc happens to interpret as accessing element `i` of `someUnion.array`, but the only way that would be allowable under the Standard would be if neither form had defined behavior, and the treatment of the `[]` syntax as member access was an extension, in which case it should be documented.

Comment: `(((int32_t)b3) << 24)` is UB when `b3 >= 128`.  Suggest `(((uint32_t)b3) << 24)`

Comment: Kamil, To be clear, you want `int16_t[2] int16words;` and not `int16_t int16words[2];`?

Comment: @Christian but it is a form of a pointer punning not union punning I disscuss

Answer (score 2):

union punning is 100% fine. there are no issues (except endianes) at all.

Comment: Even though the Standard defines the meaning of `someUnion.array[x]` as `*((someUnion.array)+(x))`, the latter form is unreliable in gcc and clang.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html

Comment: The Standard *defines* the first form as equivalent to the second.  Neither gcc nor clang reliably accommodates type punning when using the second form, even with the exact syntax the Standard specifies as equivalent to the first.  Is there anything in gcc's documentation that indicates that *the two forms are not equivalent*, and that failure to process one form meaningfully does not imply the other shouldn't be regarded as reliable?

Comment: you can't proof your claims. It is only your opinion not shared by millions developers.

Comment: The fact that gcc and clang do not regard the constructs as equivalent is easily demonstrable in godbolt.  The fact that the Standard defines them as equivalent is N1570 6.5.2.1 paragraph 2.  Which part do you disagree with?

Comment: @supercat so demonstrate it it it is `easily demonstrable in godbolt`

Comment: See https://godbolt.org/z/EJsF-S for a very straightforward demonstration.  The version that works loads from `[4*rax+u]`, i.e. `u.arr1[i].x` twice, once each before and after after storing 1 to `[4*rcx+u]`, i.e. `u.arr2[j].x`.  The version that fails only loads `[4*rax+u]` once, before the store.  Is there anything in the Standard that would suggest that the two functions shouldn't behave identically?

Comment: It does not have anything in common with the topic here. BTW using it this way - it is side effect and thus volatile is needed

Comment: The same pattern of array syntax working but the pointer-arithmetic-syntax (which is defined as equivalent) not working also happens with primitive types as in the OP question as it does with the struct Common Initial Sequence used in my example.  While `volatile` makes things work, I see nothing in the Standard that would suggest that array and pointer syntax are only equivalent when using `volatile`-qualified objects.

Comment: BTW, if everyone agrees with the way clang and gcc interpret the Standard, why are so many programs incompatible with their optimization options?  Is it because the programs are "broken", or is it because a lot of programmers believe that when the Standard uses the term "Undefined Behavior", it "identifies areas of possible conforming language extension: the implementor may augment the language by providing a definition of the officially undefined behavior", and expect that quality implementations will extend the language in ways appropriate to their target platforms and application fields?

Comment: @supercat pointers are not arrays and we have a very good example of it here. Array as a part of the union it different just the pointer referencing something.

Comment: @supercat IMO you just do nort see this tiny difference

Comment: Quoting the Standard, "The definition of the subscript operator `[]`
    is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`."  I don't happen to think the operator *should* be defined that way if the operands are an array and an integer, but I don't think there's any ambiguity in what the Standard is saying there.

Comment: Given the Standard text as quoted above, the only situations I could see in which the two syntactic forms could behave differently would be those in which neither was defined, but an implementation decided to extend the language by defining one of them despite it not being "officially" defined.  The authors of the Standard expected implementations to do that, but the maintainers of gcc have insisted that they do not claim to reliably support any undocumented behavioral guarantees not mandated by the Standard.  So what if anything guarantees the behavior when using array syntax?